# Hibernate Interceptor don't receive changed element collection

Tags: hibernate

I have an entity with `@ElementCollection` inside and I also have Hibernate Interceptor to intercept changes.

Once I change fields of entity, interceptor can intercept properly but once I only changed fields of component inside `@ElementCollection`, interceptor cannot intercept it (both entity itself and embedded component).

I also tried debugging at `onFlushDirty`, `onCollectionUpdate`, `onCollectionRecreate` but has no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is about default dirty checking of hibernate don't do it properly on PersistentSet, I have to manually check for dirty by overriding `findDirty` method and check it via `PersistentSet#isDirty` manually.